# Window.append in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to integrate this JavaScript into my Angular controller.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 paymentwindow = new PaymentWindow({
     'merchantnumber': "123456",
     'amount': "10095",
     'currency': "DKK",
     'windowstate': "4",
     'paymentcollection': "1",
     'iframeheight': "400",
     'iframewidth': "360",
     'accepturl': ""
 });
 paymentwindow.append('payment-div');
 paymentwindow.open();
```

Is there a best practice for doing that?
I need to change the merchantnumber and amount during the payment cycle.

I have a DIV where I want the payment window in the html file.

```
<div id="payment-div"></div>
```

I also included the JavaScript file from the supplier of the payment solution.

Comment: Do you want to display this data in your html?

Comment: Yes. I need to create that window on my html page. I want to set the merchantnumber and amount with values from the Controller..

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create a window on your html page using some bootstrap modal or some other library.
To get the data simply bind it with $scope in controller and fetch those value in the html modal

```
<div id="payment-div">
{{merchantnumber}}
{{amount}}
</div>
```

In the controller

```
$scope.merchantnumber = ''
$scope.amount = ''
```

Comment: Yes, that is a solution. But I want to use the window, that the supplier has created for me. Then I style that to it goes in to my site properly.

Comment: what is this window you are talking about?Is it a different view/html? If not Is it fetching data from some other source and you have to change it according to you?

Comment: The new PaymentWindow({.. is created by a paymentwindow.js file, that I'm linking to and loading before in the script section. I need to create that paymentwindow in my code, at put it in the <div id="payment-div"></div>
The supplier is hosting the paymentwindow.js file, and there by maintaining the content. That's what I want.. Not a own made solution, because I have to maintain the code to their standards/definitions.

Comment: As per your example shown it looks like it gives you some template with some data in it.So In that case you can fetch using jqlite library provided by angular and then set your own data using controller

Comment: Thanks.. I dont know jqlite libary.. But I will Google it. Do you have some good links to documentation of jqlite?

Comment: Jqlite is basic library which comes with angular js to select elements.It is not mandatory to use Jqlite .You can use Jquery as well.However ,If you want to use it here is a link [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element).So does the above answer & comments solved your problem?